# Electron with Firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, electron

I have a web applications written in React that I want to also encapsulate into Electron. The authentication part is done using Firebase `signinWithPopup` method.

When trying to authenticate electron opens a popup but nothing happens and it remains blank. I can't seem to catch any error in the console of the main app or the popup. I'm suspecting it may be an issue with the authorized domains inside Firebase but I'm not sure and I was wondering if it's even possible.

Comment: Did you find what the issue is? Having the same problem here..