# Firebase can't authenticate after building electron app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, electron

I have a problem with Firebase, React and Electron. When I use my app in dev, I use the localhost to load with `react-scripts start` , so it's loading in http://localhost:3000. I use this url to load my app with Electron.

BUT when I am trying to go in production, I use the electron-builder. I build my app with `react-script build`, it's create the build folder, and for the electron app, I change the loading url for `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html"` I use `build -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js`. It's now loading perfectly. BUT When I try to authenticate nothing happen and in the console, it says :

```
code : auth/operation-is-not-supported-in-this-environnement 
message : This operation is not supported in the environnement this is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome extension and web storage must be enable
```

How I can resolve this ?

My hypothesis it's because I don't write the url of my app in Authorized domains in Firebase Sign in method, but there is no url for my app, it's local. Does I need to load a server to employ Firebase ?

[I see a similar post but without answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057319/electron-with-firebase-authentication)

Comment: there's a deleted answer in that "similar question" with a link to yet another answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327515/using-firebase-with-electron/47617348#47617348 - does that one help?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the SDK thinks it's running from a Node.js server environment. Currently, OAuth sign in with popup or redirect is not supported in Electronjs. You would need to get an OAuth credential from an electron compatible library and use the `signInWithCredential` API.
Firebase is looking into supporting signInWithPopup/Redirect in this environment.